# call an app and close the current running app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want my app to call an other app and then close him self
I call a new app by :

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.aaa.bbb",
            "com.aaa.bbb.MainActivity"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and the new app is running fine
but I want now the app that called the intent to close and what ever I do I still see it in the running apps (as an Icon in the list)
how can I close it?

I tryed:

```
    android.os.Process.killProcess(mid);
    System.exit(0);
    finish();
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact use-case is, but you can set the `android:excludeFromRecents` attribute to true for your activity in the manifest.

Comment: I want to kill my process exactly as swiping it to the left side (by my tablet)